# phonegap build android does nothing

Tags: android, cordova, command-line-interface

I have a phonegap CLI application that until recently was working fine and I was able to publish to the Google play store in alpha testing mode.

So in the www directory I did a 'phonegap build android'
and in the platforms/android directory I did an 'ant release' to create a signed release apk.

I've been forced to upgrade my phonegap version, as the Google play store rejected my latest submission as they no longer supported the level I was using (I think it was 3... something).

So, now when I do a 'phonegap -v' I get 5.3.6.

When I'm in the www directory and do a 'phonegap build android --verbose' I get:

[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android --verbose'...

[phonegap] completed 'cordova build android --verbose'

With no time at all between the first line and the second line, no verbose output and no apk output!

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks

Graham

Comment: if you are using node 5, there is a bug, wait until it's fixed or downgrade to node 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its seems related to NodeJS 5.0... In my case the Cordova Build command seems to be failling since the update.

After some investigation its look like you can by pass the problem by running the "build script" in your platform/build folder

```
./platforms/android/cordova/build
```

Comment: Spot on!  Thanks very much for that.

Comment: Actually although it compiles and signs ok, it ignore the phonegap step that processes the www file and updates the manifest, plugins etc. I'm not at all confident that I know what that step did, in order for me to do it manually.

Comment: I confirm its bypass all the steps (prepare, update plugin, prepare manifest) you have to do it manualy (copy www, check plugin update, remove the debug boolean in your manifest.xml)

Comment: Yeah - I upvoted this because I was able to "build" - but I wish I could remove that because the app it has built is not my app but the default cordova app - this does **not** do the same as `cordova build android`

Comment: "Build script" hint helped. Interestingly, I have an old Cordova project, which builds without any problem. I have created a new one, and this did not want to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried many different settings without success. Since I cannot spend much time on this, I resorted to create a new Adobe Id, then create a new Phonegap Build project, and build from the cloud. Now, build and execution of my Phonegap project is possible.

Please note this is a workaround for those of us in a hurry. Hope this helps.

https://build.phonegap.com

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the cloud build is an option and one that I'm rapidly moving towards! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the solution here worked for me with the same problem. Had to figure it out myself.
The problem was that i've **upgraded npm** to accomodate the latest Node.js that i'm using.
With the new version of the npm (since the api version changed), cordova could not find the new resources. Therefore, you had to remove cordova and reinstall it again. Or just upgrade Cordova if yours is not up to date.

`npm install -g cordova`

should do it.

Comment: Confirmed that updating Node.js to the latest version will fix the problem.